# Unable to delete S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a s3 bucket using console, while configuration I removed the default selected user. Now when I am trying to delete the bucket using console it says access denied.
I understand I should have removed the user. However when I click on bucket name in permission it show owner: myUserName and bucket policy: no
How can I delete it?
As I understand there is owner but there is no permission to owner as I removed it while configuration.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/delete-or-empty-bucket.html

Comment: Followed [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/delete-bucket.html) still the same error.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/delete-bucket.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this in 2 ways:

First(Recommended): Delete the bucket policy and delete the bucket.

Second: Follow these steps

1. Create a new Bucket(Do not change anything, keep default).
2. Go to S3 console where all buckets are listed.
3. Select newly created bucket.
4. Click on permissions.
5. Copy the account id under owner access section.
6. Go to permissions of old bucket.
7. Add account using the copied account id.
8. Now try deleting it.

Answer (score 87):

You are not able to delete it because there is a deny effect on "s3:DeleteBucket" on all principals according to this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=815481)

You can simply follow these steps -

1. Login as **root user**. (Not as any IAM user you might have specified)
2. Go to the S3 console.
3. Click on the bucket you want to delete.
4. Under the "Permissions" tab click on "Bucket Policy"
5. Click on "Delete"

Now you will be able to delete the bucket.

Incidentally, before you click on delete if you take a close look at the last element of the "Statement" array, you'll see what was causing the problem.

Comment: This answer wins for me. The accepted answer does not even mention the exact steps with respect to AWS console interface and so is hard to understand.

Comment: @NoopurPhalak Yes. The accepted answer got me scratching my head for quite a bit too. That's why I decided to post my own one. Glad it helped :)

Comment: Well, this is by far the correct answer, simple and well explained.

Answer (score 19):

Delete bucket policy and you will be able to delete the bucket

Answer (score 1):

Better to delete that particular element of the statement array than to point blank delete everything.

Answer (score 1):

I could not delete S3 resource that was created by Elastic Beanstalk

1. Bucket policy
2. Deleting S3 again and it worked

Answer (score 1):

I successfully deleted my bucket by changing the "Action": "Deny" to "Action": "Allow" under permission tag