# Unable to delete S3 bucket as it does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Brand new AWS account today, created a bucket to host static webpages. 
Created via the web interface and configured it to be open to public (could access the page through "bucket-name.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com")

I clicked to delete the bucket via the interface and nothing happened.
It's worth noting that since then clicking the bucket and navigating through the config no shows "No data" errors on the UI. The bucket policy section is empty.

Trying to add myself back into the properties as per -[Unable to delete S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693897/unable-to-delete-s3-bucket?rq=1)
gives me "an unexpected error occurred".

It shows the following properties when you click on the bucket

```
Events 0 Active notifications
Versioning -
MFA delete -
Logging Disabled
Static web hosting Disabled
Tags 0 Tags
Requester pays Disabled
Object lock Disabled
Transfer acceleration Disabled
Permissions
Owner REDACTED
Block public access Disabled
Bucket policy No
Access control list 0 Grantees
CORS configuration No
Management
Lifecycle Disabled
Replication Disabled
Analytics Disabled
Inventory Disabled
Metrics Disabled
```

Tried via the cli

```
aws s3 rb s3://bucket-name --force --debug
aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket bucket-name
aws s3api get-bucket-policy-status --bucket bucket-name
```

which tells me the bucket does  not exist

```
fatal error: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket does not exist

remove_bucket failed: Unable to delete all objects in the bucket, bucket will not be deleted.
```

Back to the web interface I have tried creating a new bucket with the same name but it blocks me as it already exists.

Looking around online seems to indicate it's either because there is no longer a region specified or alternatley that it is simply taking a while to reflect that it has been deleted, but I have since created and deleted other buckets without issue.

Comment: It might just take a while to update. Is it working OK now?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Nailed it, took nearly a day but it has since disappeared.

Answer (score 5):

Update: Bucket disappeared of its own accord after around 20 hours. For anyone experiencing similar problems it appears patience is your only option.

Comment: thank you!! 
I am also in similar situation, have been waiting for 30 minutes to clear that bucket and keep on hitting refresh button, but its not going away

20hours is really a long wait, if its dev then its fine, how to deal with this if its production release or something, only AWS should tell